# cassandra speed. why so slow?

Tags: cassandra, benchmarking

I run cassandra in VMWARE server with Linux, 2 core, 1 GB RAM all setting are default in cassandra conf file, try to write big abount of data, md5 as key and timestamp as column. As result i have very slow write about 10 keys per second. Why so slow?

Comment: Well, the problem must be the virtual machine... Your OS, and VM together must be hogging a lot of memory... try installing on your native machine. Make sure you are not running memory hogging apps like VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this isn't a proper answer, but I think it goes towards the suitability of the question proposed:

1. You most likely wont get good feedback on this question unless you quantify what "big amount of data" actually is ...
2. because you are using VMware and not a lot of memory, it will not be representative of the true capabilities of what Apache Cassandra can provide.

http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/Cassandra-scaling-problem-in-virtualized-environment-td6474487.html

> Cassandra's really designed to manage DAS